Unable to start debugging. Program path is missin or invalid. GDB failed with this message .exe : no such file or di
When I try to debug my c code I got an error that is on the title. What should I do?
my launch.json file:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: gcc.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "C:\\mingw32\\bin",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\mingw32\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}

tasks.json file:
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\mingw32\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\mingw32\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}

My code :
int main(){
    int i, n;

    /* Kullanicidan ust sinir degeri al. */
    printf("Ust sinir degeri giriniz: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("1'den %d'ye kadar tum cift sayilar : \n", n);

    /*
     * Dongu sayacini 1'den baslat (i=1)
     * n degerine kadar git (i<=n)
     * her sefernde dongu sayacini 1 arttir (i++)
     * her seferinde i degerinin 2'ye bolunup bolunmedigini kontrol et
     * 2'ye bolunuyorsa yazdir ve alt satira gec
    */
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (i%2 == 0) //breakpoint
        {   
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
        
    }

    return 0;   
}

I edited gcc files location and its name on launch.json(Mingw TO mingw32).

gcc.exe sounds like you are on Windows. So the official guide https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw tells you to install gcc using MSYS2, and not use old mingw32.

Please choose a language between C and C++, then tag accordingly.

i recommend just using the c/c++ extension. set the compiler to c by using cntrl+alt+p then typing in edit configurations (ui), edit compiler path. vscode will do the rest for you
